# Unable to increase Tomcat 7 Perm size while executing the tomcat 7 service

Tags: java, tomcat7

Note: I need to run tomcat via service not batch file.

Execute the below command on CMD one by one.

```
set JAVA_OPTS="-Xms1024m -Xmx10246m -XX:NewSize=256m -XX:MaxNewSize=356m -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=356m"

"C:\Program Files\DSR\apache-tomcat-7.0.50\bin\service.bat" install dummy
sc config "dummy" start= auto
net start dummy
"C:\Program Files\DSR\apache-tomcat-7.0.50\bin\tomcat7.exe" //RS//dummy
```

After executing the above command facing **out of memory issue**.

Please let me know how to solve this issue.

Comment: Try this JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 
-server -Xms1536m -Xmx1536m
-XX:NewSize=256m -XX:MaxNewSize=256m -XX:PermSize=256m 
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:+DisableExplicitGC"

Comment: I tried this but doesn't work